# Finding all possible combinations of connections between nodes of a graph

Tags: python, combinations, permutation, graph-theory, python-itertools

Assume I have a graph, like the one [pictured here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qu0TA.png), where the bottom nodes are, from left to right, labeled 4,5,6,7,8.
I group the bottom nodes into three groups: (4,5), (6,7), and (8,9). Let's call them group 1, group 2, and group 3 respectively. I need to connect the nodes in group 1 to the nodes in group 2 and group 3, and I need to connect the nodes in group 2 to the nodes in group 3. Two nodes in the same group cannot connect to the same node in a different group. For instance, here is a [possible solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xF9TI.png). I am trying to figure out a nice code to find all such combinations. Ideally, I would like the answer to be in a form that looked something like this:

```
[[(4,6),(5,7),(4,8),(5,9),(6,8),(7,9)],
 [(4,6),(5,7),(4,8),(5,9),(6,9),(7,8)],
...etc]
```

where the pairs represent the connections. Here, each row represents one of the possible combinations. I have figured out a couple ways of doing this (one using many for loops and the other using itertools.product), but these methods don't scale nicely if I had, say, 25 groups with 25 nodes in each group. I also thought maybe I was on to something when I was messing around with this:

```
list1=[4,5]
list2=[6,7]
list3 = [8,9]
one_two = [list(zip(x,list2)) for x in permutations(list1,2)]
one_three = [list(zip(x,list3)) for x in permutations(list1,2)]
two_three = [list(zip(x,list3)) for x in permutations(list2,2)]
```

but I couldn't quite get it to work out. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

CLARIFICATION: I realized it may be helpful to explain why I am doing this. I am trying to find a quick way to change the values of an adjacency matrix. In my example answer above, each row would represent all of the changes I want to make to a single graph. So, for example, the first row says

```
[(4,6),(5,7),(4,8),(5,9),(6,8),(7,9)]
```

which means I would be adding an edge between nodes 4 and 6, 5 and 7, 4 and 8, 5 and 9, 6 and 8, and 7 and 9.That's the reason why I would like them to be in pairs (and in nice rows, so I can easily iterate through them to change my adjacency matrix). I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

We know:

- Each node connects to exactly one node per group
- Two nodes from the same group don't connect to the same node
- Each group has two nodes

This means that if we know the connection of a node in group A to group B, we also know the connection of the other node in A to group B.

Hence we only need to find ways in which one node connects,  and all connections of all other nodes are given.

For node 4, respecting the rules above, there are 2*2 possible ways to connect to the other groups. We can find them with

```
from itertools import product
to_group_2 = product([4], [6, 7])
to_group_2 = product([4], [8, 9])
all_possible_node_4_conns = product(to_group_2, to_group_3)

print(list(all_possible_node_4_conns))
```

output:

```
[((4, 6), (4, 8)), ((4, 6), (4, 9)), ((4, 7), (4, 8)), ((4, 7), (4, 9))]
```

Now since all connections not yet considered are given (as stated above), all that is left to do is add those missing links to the list, if that's required.

Comment: Thank you for your response! This method does work for the case where each group only has 2 nodes, but I don't think we could generalize it further. If each group had 5 nodes instead, assigning the connections of a single node doesn't solidify the connections of the other 4 nodes.